# Problems with Rendering Component in React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements, render

I'm trying to render certain content onto my screen but currently it's not showing up. I know the function is entering the if conditional since I tested it with console logging.

Here is where I write the conditional to render a certain content.

```
renderContent = (): Content => {
  this.props.contents.forEach((content:SomeType) => {
    if (content.booleanCondition){
      return <ImportantComponent contentData = {this.usefulFunction()}/>
    }
  }
}
```

And here is where I want to render everything.

```
renderEverything = () => {
  return (
    {this.renderContent()}
  );
};
```

Alternatively, is there a way I can directly write the conditional in the renderEverything so I don't have to call the function renderContent?

Comment: Are both functions on the same file and by the way could you add more source code to help you? maybe the error is not there and you have missed it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render an ImportantComponent for each content element that satisfies the `booleanCondition`:

```
renderEverything = () => {
  return this.props.contents.map(
      content => content.booleanCondition && <ImportantComponent key={content} contentData = {this.usefulFunction()}/>
  )
}
```

If you want to render only one ImportantComponent if any content element satisfies the `booleanCondition`:

```
renderEverything = () => {
  const contentToBeShown = this.props.contents.find(content => content.booleanCondition)
  if(contentToBeShown)
     return <ImportantComponent contentData = {this.usefulFunction()}/>
}
```